# Changing Lead Ownership for Siblings in Role Hierarchy

Tags: leads, role-hierarchy, sharing-rule, ownership, record-owner

I have 2 roles in my org: A & B.

They users assigned to the role A have permissions to 'Create/View/Edit the Lead object as well as permission to 'Transfer Leads' and 'Transfer Records'.

A and B are currently siblings in the role hierarchy and have read/write permissions (through sharing rules) on Leads owned by Users of the opposite role.

While a user with role A is able to edit fields on a Lead owned by B, 
if A tries to change the owner, an insufficient Permissions error is displayed.

As I understand, 2 possible solutions to this are:

1. Move B to a lower role than A in role Hierarchy.
2. Grant 'A' Modify All permission on Leads.

Are there any other alternate ways to allow A to change ownership of B's leads through sharing rules or permissions where I can avoid the 2 solutions above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.. You are right with the two Approches you mentioned.

**Approach 1:**

> A record owner, or any user above the owner in the role or territory
>   hierarchy, can transfer a single record to another user.

**Approch 2 :**

> Users with the “Modify All Data” permission, or users with the “Modify
>   All” permission for the given object, can transfer any record,
>   regardless of who owns the record.

There are 2 extra Approaches specified by SF to allow this functionality.

**Approach 3:**

> The Public Full Access and Public Read/Write/Transfer sharing settings
>   give all users the ability to transfer ownership of that type of
>   record as long as they have the appropriate “Edit” permission.

Ie. You have to change the OWD sharing for Lead as Public Read/Write/Transfer for Internal user.

**Approach 4:**

> In organizations that use territory management, users that have been
>   assigned to territories can be enabled to transfer the accounts in
>   their territories, even if they are not the record owner

Role hierarchy allows you have Vertical sharing, while Territory Management allows you to have Horizontal sharing.  Sharing even if people are not in role hierarchy.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_about_transfer.htm&type=5